# Docker compose file with yarn monorepo

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm pretty new with docker, but trying to get docker-compose handling my local dev environment. Essentially when I run `docker-compose up` it should have my api running on port `3000:3000`

This is my current `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    image: node:9
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3000:3000
    working_dir: /api
    volumes:
      - ./:/api
    command: bash -c 'yarn && cd api && yarn dev'
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.4
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./db:/data/db
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    environment:
      - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=miniokey
      - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=miniosecret
    volumes:
      - ./minio:/data
    command: ["server", "/data"]
  createbuckets:
    image: minio/mc
    depends_on:
      - minio
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      while ! /usr/bin/nc minio 9000; do sleep 2s; done;
      /usr/bin/mc config host add myminio http://minio:9000 miniokey miniosecret;
      /usr/bin/mc mb myminio/vividaura;
      /usr/bin/mc policy download myminio/vividaura;
      /usr/bin/mc mb myminio/vividaura-test;
      /usr/bin/mc policy download myminio/vividaura-test;
      exit 0;
      "
  nats:
    image: nats:1.1.0-linux
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:4222:4222
      - 127.0.0.1:8222:8222
```

The thing is, I'm using yarn's workspace feature. So I need to run yarn in the root directory then run yarn inside `/api`

This is my folder structure:

```
> /api
> /image-compose
> /src
> docker-compose.yml
> package.json
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. Had issues with the ports. This is my updated `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: node:9
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: bash -c 'yarn && cd src && yarn dev'
    depends_on:
      - api
  api:
    image: node:9
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    working_dir: /api
    volumes:
      - ./:/api
    command: bash -c 'yarn && cd api && yarn dev'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - nats
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.4
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./db:/data/db
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    environment:
      - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=miniokey
      - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=miniosecret
    volumes:
      - ./minio:/data
    command: ["server", "/data"]
  createbuckets:
    image: minio/mc
    depends_on:
      - minio
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      while ! /usr/bin/nc minio 9000; do sleep 2s; done;
      /usr/bin/mc config host add myminio http://minio:9000 miniokey miniosecret;
      /usr/bin/mc mb myminio/vividaura;
      /usr/bin/mc policy download myminio/vividaura;
      /usr/bin/mc mb myminio/vividaura-test;
      /usr/bin/mc policy download myminio/vividaura-test;
      exit 0;
      "
  nats:
    image: nats:1.1.0-linux
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:4222:4222
      - 127.0.0.1:8222:8222
```